# Python extract html webpage content using keywords

Tags: python, html, python-3.x

Using python would like to extract context by matching keywords,

Here is my python script

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
html = """ <pre>
      Companies:
       Telstra VI Huawei
      Countries:
       JPN CHN MLY
   </pre>
   <pre>
   Data center:
    US UK
   </pre>"""
r = requests.get(html)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
k = soup.find(text=re.compile("companies:")).parent.text
print (k)
```

Expected output:

```
Companies:
       Telstra VI Huawei
```

Comment: What is your question? What is your current output?

Comment: @ThomasMunk Please see my python script using that i want to print expected output. Current output is {}

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc

html = """ <pre>
      Companies:
       Telstra VI Huawei
      Countries:
       JPN CHN MLY
   </pre>
   <pre>
   Data center:
    US UK
   </pre>"""
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
pre = doc.getElementByReg('Companies:')
print(pre.text)
print('-' * 50)
print(pre.replaceReg('Countries:[\s\S]*', '').strip())
```

Result:

```
Companies: Telstra VI Huawei Countries: JPN CHN MLY
--------------------------------------------------
Companies:
       Telstra VI Huawei
```